# Recognize list structure

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Suppose I have several lists:

```
lst1={{{x1,y1},{dx1,dy1}},{{x2,y2},{dx2,dy2}},...};
lst2={{{x1,y1},dy1},{{x2,y2},dy2},...};
lst3={{{x1,y1},{dx1,{dy1n,dy1p}}},{{x2,y2},{dx2,{dy2n,dy2p}}},...};
```

where there can be several hundred entries in each list.
`{xi,yi}` are measured data which can have errors `{dxi,dyi}`.
Additionally these do not need to be symmetric, e.g. `{dxi,{dyin,dyip}}`is also possible .

I want to write a function `f[l_List]` which checks the form of the given list and then proceed in different ways.
Since the shape for a given list does not change, it is enough to check the first element.

For example:

```
g[l_List]:= If[ f[l[[1]]]=={{_,_},{_,_}} ,a ,b ]
```

Where a and b are further operations on that list.
The problem I have is finding the correct formulation for the condition in the If-statement.

I came up with `Dimensions[l[[1]]]=={1,2,2}` which works for distinguishing `lst1` and `lst2`, but fails for `lst3`, since `Dimensions[lst1[[1]]]==Dimensions[lst3[[1]]]=={1,2,2}`.

So the question is how this condition could look like.

Thanks in advance.

Additional question:
How do I color my code like it is done in most questions on this side?

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces to get the code with syntax coloring (as opposed to inline code delimited by backticks). As for your actual problem, probably something like `MatchQ[expr, {{_, _}, _}]` might be useful.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how I was able to overlook this, but it does the job.
One just needs to check the most nested structure first for it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the pattern describing your structure on the left side of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed):

```
f[l : {{{_, _}, {_, _}} ..}] := "Structure 1"
f[l : {{{_, _}, _} ..}] := "Structure 2"
f[l : {{{_, _}, {_, {_, _}}} ..}] := "Structure 3"
```

You can read up on patterns [in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html). Note that Mathematica always uses the most specific pattern that matches: Even though the first definition would also match `lst3`, it's not taken since the third one is more specific.

Now, the correct one of these 3 definitions is used, depending on the structure of the list:

```
In[1]:=  f[lst1]
Out[1]:= "Structure 1"
In[2]:=  f[lst2]
Out[2]:= "Structure 2"
In[3]:=  f[lst3]
Out[3]:= "Structure 3"
```